# Fetch data using regular expression in playframework

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to get the data from a database table using a regular expression.This is what i did:

```
def getDataRegExp(term: String): Seq[User] ={
    DB.withConnection(
      implicit connection =>
        SQL("select * from user where pseudo ~ '^{term}'").on(
        'term -> term
        ).as(User.simple *)
    )
  }
```

But i get nothing in result. 
What I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.1`

Comment: Suggestion: make sure `term` is being replaced the way you expect it to. After that it's only a postgresql question.

Comment: @pedrofurla That's what I'm trying to do. `term` is not being replaced the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I succeded in getting a result. It gives me all the user that contains the inserted `term`. I have just deleted `'` and `^` that were surrounding `{term}`. Here is the code.

```
def getDataRegExp(term: String): Seq[User] ={
    DB.withConnection(
      implicit connection =>
        SQL("select * from user where pseudo ~ {term}").on(
        'term -> term
        ).as(User.simple *)
    )
  }
```

Comment: But i still don't know how to get only the result that starts with `term`